# Presentation viewer software

Tags: software-recommendation, presentation

I am looking for a presentation(.ppt) viewer. I don't want an editor. I have to read a many presentations.
Likewise, I check many software products but all software products give an option to edit with view. I just need a viewer. Easy to switch between slides.
One problem with editor is that, if I am reading and just click anywhere and slide, something will change in slides.
Any suggestion.

Comment: Have you tried `pptview` ? https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/pptview.1.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've linked you in comments a software I googled, I didn't try it.

---

Alternatively, and that is what I do daily, you can use `okular` or `evince` in presentation mode, but it's for PDF so you need to convert them first.

For that, you can script it easily (replace with ppt instead of pptx if you need)

```bsh
for f in *.pptx ; do libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf "$f" ; done
```

Comment: Thank you, now I can convert all ppt files in pdf files in only command.